# How do I stop duplicate rows on table join in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Trying to join this table, so that i can change the code if the tutor ID matches the session tutor ID. But it shows multiple results in the calendar that its generating.

Below is the current PHP code, although the entries are being duplicated due to having multiple tutor ID's within the table. i'm not sure how to change this.

```
<?php
    $sqlAssignments = "SELECT * FROM tbl_assignments LEFT JOIN tbl_tutorModules ON tbl_assignments.module_code = tbl_tutorModules.module_code"; // 
    $qryAssignments = mysqli_query($con, $sqlAssignments); // running the query

    while($rowAssignment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryAssignments)){
        if ($_SESSION["ID"] == $rowAssignment['tutor_id']) {
            echo "{ title: '" . $rowAssignment['assignment_name'] . "', start: '" . $rowAssignment['hand_in_date'] . "', end: '" . $rowAssignment['hand_in_date'] . "', url: 'view/assignments.php?id=" . $rowAssignment['assignment_id'] . "', color: '#f1f1f1'},";
        } else {
            echo "{ title: '" . $rowAssignment['assignment_name'] . "', start: '" . $rowAssignment['hand_in_date'] . "', end: '" . $rowAssignment['hand_in_date'] . "', url: 'view/assignments.php?id=" . $rowAssignment['assignment_id'] . "'},";

        }
    }
?>
```

The actual results at the moment is that when the tutorModules has multiple tutors, the output duplicates calendar results.

Thanks

Edit: Tables look like this with some example data

tbl_tutorModules

```
con_id   module_code   tutor_id
2        ISYS30025     1
3        ISYS30025     2
```

tbl_assignments

```
assignment_id
module_code
assignment_name
assignment_weight
set_date
hand_in_date
hand_in_method
assignment_type
```

[This is the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvHdK.png)

The expected output is for these not to be duplicated.

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: Provide some more details, like desired results, so that we can understand problem easily.

Comment: Select the specific data you want (rather than *everything* - \*) with a DISTINCT clause?

Comment: thanks everyone, i have added the tables that im using.

Comment: As for the expected output i would like it so if the tutor id matches the session stored id the colour is different, otherwise it just displays normal.

Comment: But at the moment it creates new rows on join, meaning that it then duplicates the results as i echo them out.

Comment: As previously stated, using DISTINCT, with an additional GROUP BY should do it.

Comment: Please edit your request again in order to show sample data and expected result. So far you are showing two sample records for tbl_tutorModules. Now show some sample rows for tbl_assignments, too, show the result you are getting and the result you want instead.

Comment: I have added distinct to the query, im not sure what you mean by group by?

Comment: Sample data for both tables and also the expected result would help us a lot. Simplify as much as possible. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Why the edit here?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54007964/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know whether a certain tutor is involved in an assignment. So pass the tutor ID to the DBMS in order to let it find out in a query.

```
SELECT
  assignment_id, assignment_name, hand_in_date,
  case when module_code in (SELECT module_code FROM tbl_tutorModules WHERE tutor_id = ?)
    then 'yes' else 'no'
  end as tutor_involved
FROM tbl_assignments
ORDER BY assignment_id;
```

As you can see, I don't join the tables, because I'm not interested in the joined result. I merely want to look up a record in `tbl_tutorModules`. We use `IN` or `EXISTS` in SQL to look up records in another table.

See here how to pass parameters to the DBMS in mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php